# Apply a different color to the selected sorted item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am testing [jQuery sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

I have a sortable list that is working, but how do I apply a different color to the the selected item that is being dragged?

This is different to the placeholder color.

I am hoping to apply the css class `.ui-state-focus` to the selected item as shown below.

I have searched SO & Google, and tried a few things, but cannot get this to work.

Here is my code:

```
  <style>
      #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #sortable li { margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; height: 1.5em; }
      html>body #sortable li { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }
      .ui-state-highlight { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; border: 3px dashed red; background: yellow; }
      .ui-state-focus { border: 2px dotted orange; background: lime; }
  </style>

  <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
          placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it just now.

I found that the item which is being dragging has the classname `ui-sortable-helper` added.

So you can just add few lines to your css file:

```
.ui-sortable-helper { // original and wrong code: .ui-sort-helper
  background: red;
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. How did you apply that css to the code?

Comment: @user1261774 You can just add that css to your own css file, or just inside the HTML file like: `<style> /* that css */ </script>`

Comment: Ah! I see the issue, you referenced `ui-sortable-helper` in the text answer and mistyped this as ui-sorted-helper in the code example. The answer should be **`ui-sortable-helper`**

Comment: @user1261774 HAHA, my mistake!